# yacc grammar for parsing simple expressions

Tags: yacc

help me create a yacc grammar for parsing a simple expression, specifically this expression:
`1;1;1;1;1;`

It's important to consider some specifics:

1. Semicolon may be optional after the last '1'
2. The expression can be separated by a newline character, and the newline character can be placed either before or after the semicolon.

No matter what I try, I lack the skills; it's just becoming a puzzle. Here's my grammar:

```
%{
package main
%}

%union {
    token Token
}

%token<token> Number 

%%

start: expressions

expressions: Number
    | expressions NEWLINE
    | expressions SEMICOLON opt_Number
;

opt_Number: | Number

NEWLINE: '\n';
SEMICOLON: ';' ;

%%
```

It covers cases like `1;1;1;1`, `1;1;1;1;`, and `1;1;1\n;1`, but it doesn't cover `1;1;\n1;1`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would remove NEWLINE from the grammar and treat it as white space in the lexer.

Comment: Your current solution allows inputs like `1;;;;1`. Is this intended?

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Yes, that's what I wanted

Comment: @user207421 that might be a good idea

Comment: Decided to go with the option suggested by @user207421. Why didn't I think of it earlier? It really simplifies grammar writing